# Is it possible to change one segment of the current url and keep the rest of it the same in a cleaner way?

Tags: localization, multi-environment, segments

How would you go about changing one segment of the current url? I have a select in the footer that you can click on a country name and then it redirects you to the homepage of that country version of the website.

```
<!-- language: lang-twig -->
<form action="" name="dropdown">
    <select name="country-select"  id="country-select" class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;" autocomplete="off">>
        {% set locales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocaleIds() %}
        {% set locale = craft.locale %}
        {% for loc in locales %}
            {# checking if current loop has active locale #}
            {% set isHome = (loc == locale) %}
            {% if isHome %}

                {% if loc == "en" %}
                    <option value="/{{ loc | replace({'en': 'eu'}) }}" selected>Europe</option>   

                    {% set myJs %}

                        var currentCountryLocale = "Europe";
                        var currentCountryLocale = "{{ loc | replace({'en': 'eu'}) | trim('_') }}";

                    {% endset %}

                    {% includeJs myJs %}

                {% else %}
                    {% set subTags = locale|split('_') %}
                    {% set territory = subTags|length > 1 ? craft.i18n.getLocaleData(craft.locale).getTerritory(subTags|last) : '' %}  
                        <option value="/{{ loc | replace({'en': ''}) | trim('_') }}" selected>{% if territory %}{{ territory }}{% endif %}</option>  

                    {% set myJs %}

                        var currentCountryName = "{{ territory }}";
                        var currentCountryLocale = "{{ loc | replace({'en': ''}) | trim('_') }}";


                    {% endset %}

                    {% includeJs myJs %}

                {% endif %}

            {% else %}

                {% if loc == "en" %}
                    <option value="/{{ loc | replace({'en': 'eu'}) }}">EU</option>   
                {% else %}
                    <option value="/{{ loc | replace({'en': ''}) | trim('_') }}">{{ loc | replace({'en': ''}) | trim('_') | upper }} </option>   
                {% endif %}

            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

I have been trying to figure out how to switch only the country/region part of the url, which is segment(2), but all of my experiments so far have been extremely complicated and confusing and I haven't found a good solution yet. Am I missing something? There must be a more efficient way to accomplish this, as it's probably not a good idea to wrap conditionals inside of conditionals inside of more conditionals.

I also have the added complexity of needing to include a continent (Europe) as one of the versions of the website, for which I'm using the "en" locale, as you can see in the bit of code above.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, @hcone5006 and thanks for sharing what worked for you! Would you mind adding your solution as an official answer instead of an edit to your original question?

Comment: Thanks, @BradBell I've done that as you suggested. Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So!!!! I was getting confused about the various craft properties pertaining to urls, and I thought that even if I grab the path, that it would include the region segment, but surprise! {{ craft.request.path }} grabs the remaining portion of the url, after the region segment! So, I can use code that I've written above and I only need to add:

```
<!-- language: lang-twig -->

    /{{ craft.request.path }}
```

Example:

```
<!-- language: lang-twig -->

    <form action="" name="dropdown">
        <select name="country-select"  id="country-select" class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;" autocomplete="off">>
            {% set locales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocaleIds() %}
            {% set locale = craft.locale %}
            {% for loc in locales %}
                {# checking if current loop has active locale #}
                {% set isHome = (loc == locale) %}
                {% if isHome %}

                    {% if loc == "en" %}
                        <option value="/{{ loc | replace({'en': 'eu'}) }}/{{ craft.request.path }}" selected>Europe</option>   

                    {% else %}
                        {% set subTags = locale|split('_') %}
                        {% set territory = subTags|length > 1 ? craft.i18n.getLocaleData(craft.locale).getTerritory(subTags|last) : '' %}  
                            <option value="/{{ loc | replace({'en': ''}) | trim('_') }}/{{ craft.request.path }}" selected>{% if territory %}{{ territory }}{% endif %}</option>  

                    {% endif %}

                {% else %}

                    {% if loc == "en" %}
                        <option value="/{{ loc | replace({'en': 'eu'}) }}/{{ craft.request.path }}">EU</option>   
                    {% else %}
                        <option value="/{{ loc | replace({'en': ''}) | trim('_') }}/{{ craft.request.path }}">{{ loc | replace({'en': ''}) | trim('_') | upper }} </option>   
                    {% endif %}

                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </form>
```

Yay!! I wanted to share my answer because I've been working on this issue for a few days and couldn't find a solution anywhere. Maybe it will help someone else that runs into this issue when building a multi-country website with Craft. Cheers!